# Malloc affecting random integer value

Tags: c, arrays, memory, malloc

I'm writing a virtual memory simulator in C, compiling on linux, and I'm getting something rather strange. It takes in a file IO, which I put into an int* plist.

I've printed this "plist" array, and it comes out to
0 100
1 200
2 400
3 300 
etc

The problem is that it seems malloc or something is randomly changing plist[3] to 0. It doesn't seem like it should be that way, but I've put a print statement at every line of code to print plist[3], and

```
tables[i].valid = (char*) xmalloc(num_pages * sizeof(char));
```

is where it changes. plist[3] = 300 before the line, 0 after it. And it only does this when i = 2. The first 3 rounds of the loop run fine, and on round 3, it changes the values for round 4. I have no idea why, it makes little sense that malloc would change a value in an array  that's completely unrelated - is it possible I've gone over some space limit, even though I'm using the heap for basically everything? Would it just change values in random arrays if I did?

```
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){

    num_pages = plist[i] / P1;

    tables[i].page_num = (char**) xmalloc(num_pages * sizeof(char*));

    tables[i].valid = (char*) xmalloc(num_pages * sizeof(char));


    //initialize page numbers and valid bits
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        tables[i].page_num[j] = (char*) xmalloc(16*sizeof(char));
        tmp = itoa(i, tmp);
        strcat(tables[i].page_num[j], tmp);
        strcat(tables[i].page_num[j], "p");
        tmp = itoa(j, tmp);
        strcat(tables[i].page_num[j], tmp);

        tables[i].valid[j] = 0;
    }
}
```

Here's the struct for tables:

```
typedef struct s_page_table
{
    char** page_num;
    char* valid;
} t_page_table;
```

And this is xmalloc (it's just a wrapper to make it easier):

```
void* xmalloc(int s)
{
    void* p;
    p = malloc(s);
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        printf("Virtual Memory Exhausted");
        exit(1);
    }
    return p;
}
```

EDIT: If I take out both lines referencing tables[i].valid, the problem does not exist. plist[3] stays the same. num_pages is always >= 10. I set j to be 0 to 10 just to have less output for debugging purposes.

EDIT 2: If I change valid from a char* to an int* it doesn't work. If I change it to an int, it does.

Comment: Shall we *guess* what `tmp` is, where it comes from, and why it is being used in `itoa` while appearing nowhere else in the code?

Comment: Is `num_pages` less than 10? I.e. Shouldn't the `j` loop use `num_pages` as the bound instead of `10`?

Comment: I was trying to guess what `P1` might be.  @user3475234 If you post a complete ready-to-compile program, it's a lot easier for people to solve these riddles.

Comment: Check that all your `strcat`s do not overflow the amount of memory you allocated. I'd consider replacing that whole block with `snprintf(tables[i].page_num[j], 16, "%dp%d", i, j);`

Comment: Also check that `num_pages >= 10`

Comment: @WhozCraig tmp is just a char* that I use to make a unique string to identify each page.

Comment: @pat I would use num_pages, but num_pages is usually like 150 or 300 depending on the value in plist, so I set it to only do the first 10 pages, so that compiler output is less daunting

Comment: @Matt McNabb I think I allocated enough but I will check that. Does snprintf print things or does it just concatenate them? Eventually I would want the program to not print, I just want the string to use as an identifier.

Comment: My `snprintf` does the same thing as your previous code, except it stops if it is going to overflow the buffer.

Comment: I assume though, that if I want to get rid of those print statements later, I wouldn't want to use it, correct?

Answer (score 6):

There are several possibilities, including (but not limited to):

- `tables[i]` is out of bounds;
- `plist` contains a dangling pointer (i.e. it's been deallocated);
- `plist` hasn't been initialised;
- `plist` isn't as large as you think, i.e. `plist[3]` is out of bounds.

If you can't figure out the problem by looking at the code, [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) is your friend.

Comment: +1, but not sure about the first bullet. Wouldn't it be `tables[i].page_num[j]` and `tables[i].valid[j]` are out of bounds if `tables` has fewer than 4 entries or `plist[i] < 10*P1`?  The value of `P1` does not affect whether `tables[i]` is out of bounds.

Comment: @pat: You are quite right, thanks. I confused the `i` and `j` indices. I've edited the answer.

Comment: OK I went through these and I don't think these are the problem. `i` goes up to 10 - I just set it to 4 so that I could figure out what's wrong with `plist[3]`. I haven't gotten around to deallocating anything yet (cause it's still in progress and I wanted to test what I had so far). plist is initialized, and has ten spots, and I print it - it reads from file input, and I printed the output in a loop before this one, and it comes out correct. The thing is that `plist[3]` is 300 for the entirety of the loop, until i = 2 and it allocates `tables[i].valid` - if I remove the allocation, it works.

Comment: @user3475234: If you've carefully gone through the program, and still can't spot where the memory bug is, I'd encourage you to try `valgrind`. It's free and might solve the mystery in no time at all!

Answer (score 0):

OK. So I believe the problem turned out to be playing with the strings before initializing everything. I'm not entirely certain the reason, maybe someone else can elaborate, but when I encapsulated JUST the initialization in its own function, like only doing mallocs, and then separately created the strings afterwards, the plist variable was unaffected.

For those interested, the encapsulated function looked like this:

```
t_page_table* table_builder(int* p, int x, int num_tables)
{
    t_page_table* ret = xmalloc(num_tables * sizeof(*ret));
    int i, tmp, j;
    for(i = 0; i < num_tables; i++){
        tmp = (p[i]/x); 
        ret[i].page_num = xmalloc(tmp * sizeof(char*));
        ret[i].valid = xmalloc(tmp * sizeof(char));
        for(j = 0; j < tmp; j++){
            ret[i].page_num[j] = xmalloc(16 * sizeof(char));
            ret[i].valid = 0;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```